# why the header attribute of linked list is set as transient

Tags: java, linked-list

If one attribute is set transient then it's not able to be serialized, I'm wondering why the Entry header in LinkedList is set as transient. The part of source code as following: 
public class LinkedList{
    private transient Entry header = new Entry(null, null, null);
...
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because LinkedList uses for serialisation it's own methods. See LinkedList's writeObject and readObject methods.

EDITED:
Buy or rent Effective Java book from J. Bloch and read Item 75 from chapter 11 ;-)